# function not returning the correct argument

Tags: c++

I have a function declared like this

```
int * return_array(int * arr1 , int * arr2);
```

and the function is defined like this

```
int * return_array(int * arr1, int * arr2)
{
    int arr_sum[5]={0};
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        arr_sum[count] = *(arr1+count)+*(arr2+count);
        count ++;
    }
    while (count < 5);
    return (arr_sum);
}
```

this is how i am trying to access the returned array in the main function

```
int *get_arr;
get_arr=return_array(arr1,arr2);
cout << "Their sum is :"
     << endl;
for (count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
{
     cout << *(get_arr+count)
          << endl;
}
```

the first sum is correct but the rest looks to be garbage values, what might be the cause?

Comment: Consider using, and return, `std::array<int, 5>`

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an array from a function, but its scope does not go outside that function, so I'm sure you are seeing "garbage values".

You need to either allocate the space for `arr_sum` yourself in the function, or you can pass an array to be filled from the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting garbage as you are trying to return something local to function,

```
return (arr_sum);
```